# can't calculate proper total hours?

Tags: mysql

I have following fields

```
Date        InTime    OutTime   Status
2016-01-04  10:19:00  05:10:00  Out
```

I tried below query

```
SELECT sum(time_to_sec(timediff(CONCAT(`TodayDate`,' ',`OutTime`),CONCAT(`TodayDate`,' ',`InTime`)))/ 3600) as total FROM `wp_ag_punch` where UserId=$userid and TodayDate='$today'
```

but it's give -5.15 hr.

please help me to solve it

Comment: Is your OutTime in AM or PM? I believe this is the source of your problem. You'll also want to take the absolute value of the calculation, [`ABS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)

Comment: Yes,My OutTime is in PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually either your out time should be '17:10:00' or date should be different as per mysql time format.

Further after seeing your record format, you don't need to concat date with time, instead you just do your calculation on time as per below-

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`OutTime`,`InTime`)))/ 3600 AS total FROM `wp_ag_punch` WHERE UserId=$userid AND TodayDate='$today'
```

Comment: SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`OutTime`,`InTime`)))) AS total FROM `wp_ag_punch` WHERE UserId=$userid AND TodayDate='$today'

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong system architecture rather then using two fileds for date and time use only one which will work for all your cases
Please use following structure

```
DatetimeIn (timestamp)  DatetimeOut (timestamp)  Status
1451912118              1451912140               Out
```

now directly do

```
Select DatetimeIn - DatetimeOut as output
```

that will give you output in seconds

```
output
------
22
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the datetime fields as DateTime datatype, instead of trying to keep the two fields as separate. So for you initial DB setup, you would instead want:

```
| DateTimeIn          | DateTimeOut         | Status |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------|
| 2016-01-04 10:19:00 | 2016-01-04 05:10:00 | Out    |
```

Which, in turn, can be queried for the difference between the two timestamps using something like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,DateTimeIn,DateTimeOut) AS total_minutes
```

which would return:

```
| total_minutes |
|---------------|
| -309          |
```

Assuming that the later time is actually at 5 PM, the data could be expressed as:

```
| DateTimeIn          | DateTimeOut         | Status |
|---------------------|---------------------|--------|
| 2016-01-04 10:19:00 | 2016-01-04 17:10:00 | Out    |
```

and the query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,DateTimeIn,DateTimeOut) AS total_minutes
```

would return :

```
| total_minutes |
|---------------|
| 411           |
```

Or, if you wanted the time-span in hours, you only need to change that part of query like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,DateTimeIn,DateTimeOut) AS total_hours
```

to get the result :

```
| total_hours   |
|---------------|
| 6             |
```

Comment: Just one question @Anthony that how you will deal with datetime if you are running application across different timezones ?

Comment: In my experience dealing with that issue, the way to go is pick a time zone for db values and stick with it. You could use the db's tz or UTC. I vote UTC. But this wouldn't affect any db level calculations since the two fields should be at least consistent to each other. It only would only be a concern when fetching/outputting the values or saving/updating them. I advise always storing (between client and application) datetime variables as ISO 8629 formatted string or datetime object, either of which have tz explicitly built in.

Comment: its interesting, Please can you share some more info ?? What I am doing is I am storing time in timestamp formate for that I am taking int fields in database and storing timestamp integer values, and according the client timezone I display it. Let me know your thought

Comment: Erp, ISO-8601 I meant

Comment: for some systems, using epoch values (unix timestamps) would work for what you are describing, since it's really just an integer (seconds since 01/01/1970), but it has a pretty small range (roughly 68 years) when it is a 32-bit signed integer. Also as an integer, it is not inherently a "date time value" to any language, which makes it fairly portable but also prevents using built-in date functions of that language unless it is converted into a datetime type variable. so that means you have to deal with any math or conversions on your own, which means more potential for errors.

Comment: also, if you are handling user timezone on your own at the application level, you are very certainly heading for a disaster at some point or another, which will be a much bigger nightmare if this data (as it appears to be) is storing employee start and end times for their job (or anything else related to the user getting paid or getting credit for something). people get really really mad when technology screws up their paycheck. take my word for it.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, also looking for any link where same things described in well define way, so if you have any please share it with me, Again thanks for your guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT (time_to_sec(timediff(OutTime,Intime)) / 3600) as total FROM `wp_ag_punch` where UserId=$userid and TodayDate='$today'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.just change the 12 hour format to 24 hour format and use below query.

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`OutTime`,`InTime`)))) AS totals FROM `wp_ag_punch` where UserId=$userid and TodayDate='$today'